# Got confused with the following JS priorities

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webbrowser-control, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

During the interview, I got these questions because of which I code confused.

1. Which one has higher priority callback or promise?
2. Are Fetch, setInterval also macro tasks like setTimeOut?

Comment: Neither question makes a lot of sense, especially the second one.

Comment: @NeelRathod if I found with searching I would never post it here.

Comment: @Pointy You are right maybe they also didn't know the answer and tried to find something for saying no.

Answer (score 3):

Those questions are related to the event loop.
I love [this explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) from Jake Archibald.

The answers to interview questions would be

1. `Which one has higher priority callback or promise?` -> I think what interviewer meant here is the priority of micro and microtask ques. Since promise accepts callbacks itself it may be a little confusing. Microtask queue has a higher priority than a macro. It means that the event loop will execute all callbacks in the microtask queue(aka promises) first and then in macro. (It's not really true because there is also a render task queue which is executed right after microtask que) you can check this [video for more info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1kqx6AenYw).
2. `Are Fetch, setInterval also macro tasks like setTimeOut?` -> Fetch uses promise - so it's microtask. setInterval and setTimeout are macrotasks.

Comment: Yes I think you're correct about what they were asking. Though that's stuff I've gotten familiar with by reading and answering SO questions, I question whether that sort of arcana is often useful for day-to-day programming.

Comment: It's crucial to understand the flow in which your code is executed. You won't face it on a daily basis but knowing this topic will save your time and effort when it comes to some sort of asynchrony bug in your code.

Comment: Oh I'm definitely glad I know it, and your answer is top quality stuff :)